# Before-queue Content Filter won't inject data back to Postfix

Tags: postfix, smtp, content-filter

I have been building a before-queue filter with Postfix on NodeJS to retrieve the data from outgoing mails, remove the attachments, upload them on a CDN and inject back the URLs in the outgoing mail.

So far, nothing too complicated, I guess, as Postfix supports doing this via the [Before-Queue Content Filter](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html).

After implementing the filter and following the Postfix documentation, I am able to retrieve outgoing mails and to send them back to Postfix.

However, Postfix does not recognize the incoming mail via the "proxy"-specific configuration  as being injected back via the before-queue content filter. It will still add it to the queue and send it properly but it won't close the session opened by the SMTP client at first.

I have been looking at this bug for some weeks now and browsed the entire web looking for answers, but this subject does not seem to be much documented. I saw that Milters could be another solution to the problem but it seems more complicated than just using SMTP to communicate with Postfix.

Here are the configuration files :

master.cf:

```
submission inet n                               -                               -                               -      smtpd
        -o syslog_name=postfix/submissions
        -o smtpd_proxy_filter=127.0.0.1:9830
        -o smtpd_proxy_ehlo=mail.clebard.cloud
        -o smtpd_proxy_options=speed_adjust
        -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=no
        -o smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file=${config_directory}/dh2048.pem
        -o smtpd_enforce_tls=no
        -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
        -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
127.0.0.1:9821  inet    n                       -                       -                       -                      smtpd -v
        -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
        -o syslog_name=postfix/afterfilter
        -o smtpd_enforce_tls=no
        -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=no
        -o smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file=${config_directory}/dh2048.pem
        -o smtpd_enforce_tls=no
        -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
        -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

(this configuration is insecure to be used in production but I tried to remove as much complexity as possible)

`127.0.0.1:9830` is the before-queue content filter server and I configured Postfix to listen for returning mails on `127.0.0.1:9821` with the second configuration of the file.

Here is what I send back to Postfix using my filter :

```
EHLO localhost
AUTH PLAIN {token}
XFORWARD HELO={client_name} NAME={client_name} ADDR={client_addr} PROTO=SMTP
XFORWARD IDENT={message_id}
MAIL FROM: {sender}
RCPT TO: {recipient}
DATA
...
.
QUIT
```

Here is the trace on the filter logs :
[Logs when a mail is sent using the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysceJ.png)

And here is what I have been seeing on Postfix :
[proxy-reject : queue file write error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8gpO.png)

All commands have been detected by Postfix when the filter sends them, but the `data=0/1` response of the original inbound mail indicates that the DATA has not been received. In fact, the error seems to happen when the `submission` process tries to add the proxy content into the queue.

I hope that I explained everything clearly, as I would really need some help on this...

Comment: Quote a full set of logs - from postfix being (re)restarted to the message being rejected. I suspect *another* log line that clarifies what happened when trying to send the message to the filter - if not, add the `-v` flag to the receiving smtpd instance as well.

Comment: Not necessarily part of your current problem, but you *must* limit the number of simultaneous processes accepting messages (e.g.set the `maxproc` column in master.cf, you probably want that lower than the overall `default_maxproc_limit`). The default behaviour when freely competing for resources is inappropriate in SMTP context. Senders would experience unclear feedback when trying to send while CPU cycles, memory and/or filter processes are exhausted.

Comment: @anx Of course, here is the full log after reboot until the end of a mail sending : https://pastebin.com/TPsEN2K2